# Merging datatables doesn't alter rowstate

Tags: c#, merge, datatable

I have two datatables with identical schema, and i want to get the differences between them. I am trying to apply `Merge` for this. Code reads easier, so a little example:

```
//Create first datatable
var o = new DataTable{Columns = { "id", "value"}};
//Add a datarow
o.Rows.Add(1, "test");
//Set PK
o.PrimaryKey = new[]{o.Columns[0]};
//Set RowState to Unchanged
o.AcceptChanges();

//Create copy of first datatable
var m = o.Copy();
//Change a value 
m.Rows[0]["value"] = "test2";
//Set RowState to Unchanged
m.AcceptChanges();

//Merge
o.Merge(m);
```

Right up to the merge everything works as expected; I've got two datatables, each with one row with the same `id`, but a different `value` ("test" and "test2").
After the merge I expected datatable `o` to have one row with id=1 and value="test2". This is true. I also expected that one row to have `RowState="Modified"`. This is not true, it has `RowState="Unchanged"`. Why is this?

I have read a couple of answers to broadly similar questions you're supposed to call `EndEdit()` on every row. Surely that cannot be the answer, this is the whole purpose of `Merge()`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the method overload that you can use to preserve the state:

> **preserveChanges** *Boolean*
>
> `true`, to preserve changes in the current `DataTable`; otherwise
>   `false`.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.merge?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Check the test here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KI7xPe

Comment: I tested the overloads on my real code and it didn't work there. Guess I've got another bug to sort, as this seems entirely correct. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. And if you are playing with code, sometimes try to do a "Clean" and "Build" process. Sometimes works for me!